# Configuring Apache to parse server side includes with .html files

Tags: html, .htaccess, configuration, ssi

I am trying to configure Apache to use .html files instead of .shtml files with server side includes. I have read about using "XBitHack On" in my httpd.conf file and .htaccess file, but I don't know where to put this.

I have found this info:

"You need to set the execute bit of each file needing to be parsed. This is done by the Unix command chmod +x fileName.html. This can be done either through a telnet/ssh connection from the command line, or within most FTP clients check all the execute checkboxes."

My question is about the quotes above: where do I run this command? On the server? I am using MAMP locally.

I've read some of the related questions, but they seem to relate to getting more basic set up of ssi (I have ssi's working with the .shtml extension) - my question is more about getting .html files working with ssi's.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the answer as an *answer*, otherwise people won't understand immediately that this question is solved.

Comment: @jackJoe - tried but didn't have enough reputation to answer it under a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of going around in circles and tearing my hair out, I have found the solution: I updated this bit of the httpd.conf file that i thought i had updated numerous times before to recognize the .html file extension for ssi:

```
 AddHandler server-parsed .html
 AddType text/html .html
 AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

where I changed .shtml to .html as you see above. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Glad it was able to help you out.